# how to see each connection use of bandwidth?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, network-monitoring

I have a linux vps server and I want to see the current network connections and upload/download rate of each one. Is there any simple command that fulfill this purpose?

Comment: No there isn't.  You would need to install something like a netflow collector such as ntop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many tools available, although you will have to install a network monitoring system to get per-process bandwidth information.

In order of setup ease:

A simple package that does not require a lot of setup is [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/). This will show you bandwidth per process. [image: iftop screenshot] This is probably what you want, if you want a simple real-time solution.

- To just get per-interface bandwidth, `bwm-ng` is a small package that shows you real-time usage per interface.
- `netstat` will list your open connections, and should already be present on most systems
- [ntop](http://www.atoptool.nl/) is a very useful tool for system monitoring, that can also monitor per-process TCP connections, IF you install a kernel module to support network monitoring.
- [Gacti](http://www.cacti.net/), [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) and [ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) are several more heavy weight systems that can do network monitoring per host/system/service/protocol/etc depending on setup for one server to an entire enterprise network. See [mediawiki server monitoring](http://ganglia.wikimedia.org/latest/) for a real-life example of `ganglia` in action.

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple package called **nethogs** that shows the bandwidth used by individual processes and sorts the list, putting the most intensive processes at the top.

It's a common package; the installation should be easy:

```
# Ubuntu or Debian
$ sudo apt install nethogs

# Fedora or CentOS
$ sudo yum install nethogs -y
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Real time usage continuous polling in 5 seconds interval using native `netstat`

```
# netstat  --interfaces=eth0 -c 5
Kernel Interface table

Iface       MTU Met    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0       1500   0 **601670041**      0      0      0 290653338      0      0      0 BMRU
eth0       1500   0 **601796657**      0      0      0 290721761      0      0      0 BMRU
```

using `awk` you can just watch a particular field that you are interested, below example you'll just watch for 2 RX and TX columns to show how many packets have been received or transmitted error-free (RX-OK/TX-OK)

```
# netstat --interfaces=eth0 -c 5 |awk '{ print $4 "\t" $8 }'
RX-OK   TX-OK
605142559       292429624
605142595       292429661
```